# Cactus tip breakdown

Tags: cactus

I just bought a trichocereus top cut from a distant source in Australia’s. Arrived looking in a good state and is happily rooting (arrives with a single root, now 6); haven’t watered as yet. Noticed the tip of the cactus has broken down with brownish edges. Used a microscope to inspect for bugs but can’t see anything. Presume it’s some form of rot but want to check before cutting the tip off! [image]